# Not able to connect to web service from angular client

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to consume the web api

**API:-**

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins="http://IP:4200")
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1")
    public class BasicAuthController {
            @PostMapping(path = "/authenticate")
            public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) {
                
                log.info("end createAuthenticationToken method");
                return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetailsinfo);
            }
    }
```

**Client:-**

```
authenticationService(formData) {
      return this.http.post<any>('/api/v1/authenticate',   formData).pipe(map((res) => {
       debugger;
    }));  
  }
```

**proxy.config.json**

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://IP:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

[image: client error]

I have run the client application using `ng-serve`

Answer (score 0):

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Try starting the application using this command to make use of the proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your proxy conf on your angular.json file. section serve take a look to this exemple :

```
 "serve": {

          "options": {
            ...
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json",
            "aot": true
            ...
          }
}
```

Or as said previously you can start your app with --proxy-config proxy.conf.json